# Latest iOS Safari not supported in @telnyx/webrtc, even though the documentation says latest version is supported?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, webrtc

Working on an application that uses @telnyx/webrtc to enable the user speak to the organization's support number.
Documentation -> https://developers.telnyx.com/docs/v2/voice/webrtc/resources/js_client/

When I used the TelnyxRTC object to make calls as per their documentation, calls were initiated successfully without issues, but then I had an issue with the audio-out. The output audio was routed to speaker (not earpiece) of the phone even if earphones / bluetooth audio devices were connected to the phone.

Then I learned from the documentation that I can use client.getAudioOutDevices() to get the list of connected audio devices and I can set to whichever one I wanted. Great.,

But this method (client.getAudioOutDevices()) worked only in Android phones (in Chrome) and not iPhones (in Safari), as a result I was not able to set the audio-out to a device because I didn't see any device listed using client.getAudioOutDevices() in the first place.
[image]

I then happened to see their documentation in which they say in iOS, Safari is the only browser that supports Telnyx and not Chrome/Firefox.

[image]

They have a property 'supportWebRTC' which says if the browser is supported or not. When I print this, I observed that this propertry was false in iOS Safari also (I checked with Safari 17).
[image]

But, I am able to call the support number using an iPhone (with the problem of not being able to route the audio to an earpiece).

Is there any other method should I try?

Or am I missing anything?

FYI-> I am using the latest 2.9.0 version of @telnyx/webrtc